# Using variables in #{select} tag attributes

Tags: java, playframework

I have a page in my app with a dynamically-generated form, in which I need a number of `<select>` elements.  Since I don't know in advance how many there will be, I need to put an ID number in the `name` attribute of each `<select>`.  I'm trying to use the built-in `#{select}` tag ([documentation here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/tags#select)) like so:

```
#{ select 'select_' + ${IDnum}}
...options, etc...
#{/select}
```

When I do that I get a MissingMethodException:

```
 No signature of method: Template_1009.$() is applicable for argument types: 
(Template_1009$_run_closure1_closure2_closure3) values: 
[Template_1009$_run_closure1_closure2_closure3@ad2388] Possible solutions: 
_(java.lang.String), is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), get(java.lang.String).
```

When I instead do:

```
#{ select 'select_${IDnum}'}
```

the page renders correctly, but the select element renders like this in view-source:

```
<select name="select_${IDnum}" size="1" >
```

So, how do I get the value of `${IDnum}` into the name attribute?  I can do this with normal HTML `<select>` tags, but I'll need to write some Javascript to emulate Play's `value:${x}` functionality that I really don't want to bother with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
#{select 'select_'+IDNum}
```

Comment: That did it!  So you can use the bare variable name as long as you're inside some template tag?  Good to know.

Comment: Indeed, I have been there and asked myself the same question :p